# What is _GetExceptDLLinfo?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I'm working on a Java project that calls a native Windows executable with a Java [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object. Sometimes I see an exception in the native code and the symbol `_GetExceptDLLinfo` appears in the native stack trace. Is there some meaningful exception to capture and if so, how do I capture it?

Comment: It's unclear what is being asked here. From your question it follows that you already have a stack trace and some information about the nature of the exception (which you didn't publish here). What else do you need?

Comment: This symbol appears in a stack trace frame (several frames sequentially actually). I wondering whether this symbol indicates some exceptional condition and how to recover information about that exception.

Answer (score 2):

`_GetExceptDLLinfo` apparently can show up when the debugger fails to find the correct function name for an address. It will likely be followed by `+0xCRAZYBIG`. Normally you'd expect to see something like `+0000003a` which means the 59th byte of the `_GetExceptDLLinfo` function.